# Array element as non type template argument

Tags: c++, c++03

is it possible to overcome this problem:

```
                class Constants
                { 
                    static Std_ReturnType dtcSitzheizungSchalteMittelkonsoleHlTasterHaengt( UInt8 const value )
                    {
                        return Rte_Call_demSitzheizungSchalteMittelkonsoleHlTasterHaengt_SetEventStatus( value );
                    }

                    static DTCSetter * const DTCSETTER_WITH_NO_DID[SEAT_HEATING_DTCS_COUNT]; //how to use an element of this array as a non type template parameter ?
                };

                template class ButtonStuckPolicy< &Constants::dtcSitzheizungSchalteMittelkonsoleHlTasterHaengt >; //works
```

in C++ 03?

In general, is it possible to pass a static array element as a non type template parameter ?

Thanks

Comment: Template arguments have to be known at compile time. And the value of x[0] right now isn't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Borgleader: what about `const int x[] = {1,2,3,4};`?

Comment: @Borgleader There is a static array of function pointers, and what I am trying to do is, instead passing the function pointer itself as a template argument, just pass the element of the array which holds the function pointer. It is just for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: @6502 Is that whats in the code? No it isnt. The important part though was "What are you trying to do?"

Comment: You are not using an array element as non-type template argument, you are using the address of an element. This is quite different.

Comment: I suggest using C++11, for aesthetic reasons :)

Comment: @Potatoswatter Non an option unfortunately..

Comment: I suggest reverting your edit, for aesthetic reasons. Now the question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address of any object with external linkage is fair game in C++03. But the *value* is not, unless it is `const` and initialized with an integer constant expression. Subobjects, as you have, need not apply until C++11.

What you have is passing an address argument to an `int` parameter, which just won't work in any context.

This is OK in C++11:

```
const int x[100] = {}; // zero-initialize
template<int T>
class foo;
foo<x[0]> y;
```

So is this:

```
int x[100];
template<int *T>
class foo;
foo<&x[0]> y;
```

This is OK in C++03 as well because it uses the address of the whole, named object:

```
int x[100];
template<int *T>
class foo;
foo<x> y;
```

Comment: But he is not passing a value, he is passing an address - i see `<&x[0]>`, not `<x[0]>`

Comment: @j_kubik Please reload, I posted a bit too early and changed a lot.

Comment: @Potatoswatter But how can I use, `x[5]` for example ?

Comment: @FailedDev You can't use the `[]` operator in a constant expression in C++03, just as your compiler told you. What do you want from me?

Answer (score 0):

My solution - create template:

```
template <int* arr, int index>
class indexer{
public:
    static inline int* element(){ return arr+index; }
};
```

then you just say

```
template <int* arr, int index>
foo{
   // Here use indexer<arr,index>::element();
};

int x[10];
foo<x,0> f;
```

or perhaps even:

```
template <typename T>
bar{
   //here use T::element();
};

int x[10];
bar<indexer<x, 0> > b;
```

It's not as beautiful as `foo<&x[0]>`, and all your classes specialized on `int*` will have to change specialization, but you will probably not get it better (and working;)